# MCP6022 as an ADC driver for STM32F401 Black Pill

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, driver

I am trying to make an ADC driver (MCP6022 op-amp) for a DSO oscilloscope using [STM32F401 Black Pill board](https://stm32world.com/wiki/Black_Pill). The Black Pill can do up to 2.4 Msps but my limitation is the input driver which barely supports an input signal of 100 kHz (at this frequency, a sine wave has already become triangular).

From the [MCP6022 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MSLD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP6021-Data-Sheet-DS20001685.pdf), I expected the gain to be faithful to at least 400 kHz:

[image: Open loop gain vs frequency]
*Figure 1 - Open loop gain vs frequency*

[image: Max Voltage vs frequency]
*Figure 2 - Max Voltage vs frequency*

Here is my basic design.
[image: ADC driver]
*Figure 3 - ADC driver*

My question is, what is the mistake in my design that results in such a small bandwidth?

Comment: JOHN KARIUKI - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). In order to help you, I found what I believe to be the source link for the copied images & added it. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess - if your schematic is accurate - one of your problems is biasing a single supplied amplifier to half supply voltage. The signal *and* the bias voltage are amplified and will most likely cause the amplifier to hit the positive rail on the output.

Since you already have LTspice going: Why don't you actually simulate your circuit in an attempt to reproduce the issue? Nobody knows what you actually built and how you are measuring. With a 100 % reproducible simulation, it's more likely that people may be able to help you.

Comment: It still behaves the same (acting like a low pass filter) at high frequency even when I use it as a unity buffer. So did I misunderstand it as a high bandwidth opamp as it was advertised(10MHz).

Comment: @JOHNKARIUKI Did you also take the "Slew Rate" of the amplifier into account? I don't believe that the GBW of the amplifier is the problem here.

Comment: @feyman Maybe that is the problem. With a slew rate of 7V/μS and some formula I got, fmax = SR / 2πA, [From this](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/eu/semiconductor/knowledge/faq/linear_opamp/what-is-the-maximum-frequency-at-which-an-op-amp-can-be-used.html). and input voltage of 4V, I get Fmax to be 270kHz. I hope that is enough analysis to give up that particular opamp and hunt for a different one?